# Malloc in a loop, are all allocated blocks consecutive?

Tags: c, memory-management, pointers

I have a function in which I make use of a local array. I would like to return a pointer to this, but of course one cannot do this unless one manually allocates memory. Therefore I would like to know if allocation like so:

```
for(i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    llist[i] = malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct));
}
```

can be later freed like so:

```
// (where ptr is a pointer to the first allocation in llist)

for(i = 0; i < 26, i++)
{
    free(ptr);
    ptr += sizeof(SomeStruct);
}
```

Edit:

Seems I can't do this. Is there any way in which I could free all the memory given only a pointer to the first element? Or should I take a different approach entirely?

Comment: Can't you just do `malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct))*26` outside the loop?

Comment: @K-ballo Just to be clear, do I want to do `malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct)) * 26;` or `malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct) * 26);`?

Comment: It should of course be `malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct) * 26)`, my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it cannot. There is no guarantee that these blocks are allocated consecutively. In fact, they are almost certainly not with all the modern implementations I've seen. Most store the size of the block and often other information immediately before each block. Also, if your memory is fragmented, the blocks might wind up anywhere in the free space between other data, where there is not sufficient room to place them consecutively.

Comment: Damnation. Is there any way all blocks can be freed later on given only a pointer to the first element?

Comment: If I were to do `llist = malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct) * 26);` wouldn't that have `llist` pointing to the entire block of memory, rather than the first item?

Comment: Yes. So then you make `llist` a `SomeStruct*` and access it with `[]` just like you do now, except there is no need for an extra dereference, so it would be `llist[i].member` rather than `llist[i]->member`.

Comment: Ahh, intriguing. I didn't know you could do that (new to C). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. In the first empty space `malloc` finds it might only be place for one struct. If that's the case, the next block will be placed somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you do inside the loop. Some functions will allocate buffers internally, which means that malloc() could be called behind your back. In your simple loop, the values SHOULD be consecutive. As well, once you throw in multi-threading, all bets are out the window, as something in another thread could malloc() memory as well.

The actual allocation spot also depends on how fragmented your memory is. There may not be enough consecutive blocks to handle your request, so the actual allocation could be from anywhere in the free space.

Comment: In very few implementations will these be consecutive.  Even in release builds, it's common for the heap to keep track of the allocation size between each of the allocations.

Comment: You *should* change "SHOULD" to "could" or "might." `malloc()` makes no promises about where a given block will be allocated, so you *must not* rely on sequentially allocated blocks being located sequentially.